# How to read this step climb profile? FL STEPS CYUL/0330/TUDEP/0340/NETKI/0350

Tags: flight-plans

How to read this step climb profile?

FL STEPS CYUL/0330/TUDEP/0340/NETKI/0350

I know CYUL is departing point but what do 0330 represents? The altitude in Feet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FL330 is the initial cruising altitude after departing CYUL. At TUDEP, a climb to FL340 is planned, and at NETKI, there is another climb to FL350.

Comment: FL330 is not 33,000 ft (or at least, will rarely be 33,000 ft)

Comment: @Simon Should've put pressure altitude there.